# Convert old AVI files to a modern format

Tags: video, conversion

we have a collection of old home videos that were saved in AVI format a long time ago. I want to convert these files to a more modern format because the Totem Movie Player that comes with Ubuntu 10.4 seems to be the only program capable of playing them.

The files seem to be encoded with a MJPEG codec, and playing them in VLC or Windows Media Player plays only the sound but there is no video.

**Avidemux** was able to open the files, but the quality of the video is severely degraded: The video skips frames and is interlaced (it's not interlaced when playing it in Totem).

Neither **ffmpeg** nor **mencoder** seems to be able to read the video stream. mencoder reports that it is using ffmpeg's codec. Here's a section from its output:

```
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
[mjpeg @ 0x92a7260]mjpeg: using external huffman table
[mjpeg @ 0x92a7260]mjpeg: error using external huffman table, switching back to internal
Unsupported PixelFormat -1
Selected video codec: [ffmjpeg] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MJPEG)
```

while running `ffmpeg` produces the following:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.avi output.avi
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Mar  4 2010 12:35:30, gcc: 4.4.3
[avi @ 0x87952c0]non-interleaved AVI
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:15.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 22447 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 720x544, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, avi, to 'output.avi':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 720x544, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame=    0 fps=  0 q=0.0 Lsize=     143kB time=15.23 bitrate=  76.9kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:119kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 20.101777%
```

So the problem is that output does not contain any video, as evidenced by the `video:0kB` at the end.

In all of the above cases the audio comes out fine.

So my question is: What can I do to convert these files to a more modern format with more modern codecs?

Comment: your old videos won't work in vlc? how old are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For easy transcoding [arista](http://packages.ubuntu.com/arista) [image: Install arista] can be used.

Like totem it uses gstreamer as backend and so should be able to read your files.

Comment: Arista worked, but thank you most of all for pointing out GStreamer. A search on Google allowed me to convert these files with gst-launch, which is the solution I prefer since it allows me to write a script to convert all the files at once.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend trying the other MJPEG codecs mplayer has. `mplayer -vc help` lists the whole lot. Some of them depend on Win32 DLL codecs, so you might need to consider the medibuntu packages.

Comment: +1: When it comes to supporting weird formats, there's little that `mplayer` isn't capable of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I struggled a bit to find the correct command line options to make it work (which is strange, since gst-launch (which I used in the end)'s command line options are even worse)

Comment: @iWerner the two are arcane, but gst is indeed more tractable. Cheers.